# Problema con captive portal + mysql usando varying logued

Tags: mysql

Estoy usando pásense como firewall principal para mi proyecto fin de ciclo y tengo un primer problema. El portal cautivo cuando lo creo inicialmente corta la red a todos los que estén dentro de la red, eso va bien, pero el portal que debería generarse automáticamente no sale, simplemente se queda cargando sin más. He probado con radius, usuarios locales y sin autenticación y nada, no funciona, aunque imagino que con esta última no debería. ¿Que puedo hacer?

Inicialmente para probar tengo el portal cautivo apuntando hacia la LAN pero en el proyecto apuntará hacia la WAN ya que controlará el acceso hacia el interior de la red que hay un servicio que quiero sacar fuera pero el puerto no se abre y sin portal desde fuera no veo el servicio. También me gustaría saber cómo puedo con el mysql que tengo en la red interior obtener del pásense la variable que guarda la cantidad de logrados en un momento determinado y hacer cosas con ella en mysql es decir el número. ¿Alguna idea?

Comment: Bienvenido Saúl!, edite un poco tu pregunta ya que puede ser cerrada si no es escrita únicamente en español. Saludos!

Comment: Esta pregunta sale traducida con post en inglés fiera de stackoverflow.com en español?

Comment: Al menos yo no entiendo esta pregunta. En que lenguaje estas haciendo el portal?